# Losing columns names when writing sparkdataframe with sparkR write.df

Tags: r, azure, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

**Context**

I'm working on an azure HDI R server cluster with rstudio and sparkR package.
I'm reading file, modifying it and then i want to write it with write.df, but the problem is that when i write the file, my column names disappear.

My code is the following:

```
write.df(spdf,"///Output/File","csv","overwrite",header=T)
```

here is the file i want to write in csv format

```
Num,Letter
5.5,a
9.,b
5.5,c
9,d
5.5,e
9,f
5.5,g
9,h
5.5,i
9,j
```

here is the file i get:

```
    0,1
    5.5,a
    9.,b
    5.5,c
    9,d
    5.5,e
    9,f
    5.5,g
    9,h
    5.5,i
    9,j
```

Comment: Put your code here, you have to set "header" option true to have the header in your output file. Like this: write.df(..., header = "true",...).

Comment: Thank you my friend

Comment: sucks that this is completely undocumented :\